# s/// and regular expression in Perl

Tags: regex, perl, operators, substitution

I'm a newbie to Perl and I found this test CGI script in my Apache installation and I would like to know what it does, especially in one of the two `s///` lines.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

print "Content-type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1\n\n";
foreach $var (sort(keys(%ENV))) {
    $val = $ENV{$var};
    $val =~ s|\n|\\n|g;
    $val =~ s|"|\\"|g;
    print "${var}=\"${val}\"\n";
}
```

The `$val =~ s|\n|\\n|g;` line replaces every occurrence of `\n` with `\\n`. But why?

And what about the `$val =~ s|"|\\"|g;` line? I think it's a substitution, but it seems to have a weird form.

Comment: Oh, and don't be thrown by the use of '|' instead of '/' - perl lets you do that... (mainly because, when working with html, it's nice not to have to constantly escape '/')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The `$val =~ s|\n|\\n|g;` line replaces every occurrence of `\n` with `\\n`.

More precisely, it replaces each new line with a common escape sequence that represents a new line.

> But why?

There lies the land of pure speculation. The content-type is `text/plain` so there is no obvious reason to do it.

> `$val =~ s|"|\\"|g;` line? I think it's a substitution, but it seems to have a weird form.

It replaces `"` with an escape sequence representing a `"` in many contexts (but not plain text). Again, there is no obvious reason to do it from the context it is presented in.

---

To hazard a guess. It looks like it is designed to dump the server's environment to a text file from which it can be copy/pasted to be used elsewhere.

Comment: "It looks like it is designed to dump the server's environment to a text file from which it can be copy/pasted to be used elsewhere." Yes.  This is what I was getting at in my answer, when I said "Looks like it's trying to escape stuff for some other level of evaluation", but this way of putting it is clearer.

Comment: I thought that `"|\\"` was a string to be interpreted as it is. Maybe I was misled by the coloring of my text-editor.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's trying to escape stuff for some other level of evaluation.  I.e. something else is going to need to see `\n`, but that something else would not see one `\` as a literal `\`, so it needs it escaped first, `\\`.  Same goes for the `"`.  Something else needs it escaped as a literal, i.e.,  `\"`, and it first needs to ensure that the `\` is preserved as a literal `\` via `\\`.

Answer (score 0):

Your explanation of the first substitution is correct. The second substitution is similar: it replaces each occurrence of `"` with `\"`.